# How to increment JavaScript getElementById variable inside one function?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I need to increment my variable count in the `add function` that works when users click the button. I know it can be done if I somehow declare the `var count` outside this function, and then put `count++` so everytime user clicks the button it has the new value, but you can see in my code that I need it to be declared inside.

So for each index (for example: 1,2,3...) the `var count` should work separately, and increment only under that function.

The problem is that whenever user clicks the button, it goes back to the var c in the first line and increment thing doesn't work :(

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function add(index) {
    var count = document.getElementById("A"+index).innerHTML;
    count = parseInt(count);
    count++;
    var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
    textarea.name = "txt" + index + count;
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = textarea.outerHTML;
    document.getElementById("inner"+index).appendChild(div);
}
</script>
```

**For example**: When index is 2 and var c gets number 3 from div, the following textarea name should be -> txt24, txt25, txt26, etc...

Comment: Use `count = parseInt(count)`, not `parseInt(count);`

Comment: it doesn't solve me the problem of incrementing :(

Answer (score 1):

Let's attack this with a "dictionary" for storing the counts for each of your parent elements, and let's keep that outside of your `add()` function:

```
var elementCounts = {};
```

And now let's adjust the `add()` method to put an initial count in this object if it doesn't exist, or update it if it does. Then you can just read and increment the values in the object on subsequent calls:

```
function add(index) {
    // build a key based on the index
    var key = 'A' + index;

    // Check if the key (property) exists in our dictionary (object)
    if (key in elementCounts) {
        // it's there, increment the count
        elementCounts[key]++;
    } else {
        // it's not there, let's add it and start it at 1
        elementCounts[key] = 1;
    }

    var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");

    // in this line, simply access the current count from the dictionary
    textarea.name = "txt" + index + elementCounts[key];

    // and the rest of the code remains the same
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = textarea.outerHTML;
    document.getElementById("inner" + index).appendChild(div);
}
```

Comment: I changed this according to your suggestions, but it only solves the integer problem. It still won't increment. The problem is that even I change count variable to number - for example 12. It gives me the number 13 everytime I click the button. Instead of 13, 14, 15...

Comment: The A field is actualy div id looking like this: id="A1", id="A2" etc... And these divs have different numbers inside from time to time.

Comment: @user3244442: Ah, I got it now. I'm working on an update to my answer with an idea I have.

Answer (score 0):

You may keep your data inside any var, like the button itself :-)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title> Bla! </title>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            function Count(obj) {
                if (! obj.data) obj.data = 0;
                obj.data++;
                var div = document.createElement('div');
                div.id = 'id_' + obj.data;
                div.innerHTML = "This is Number:" + obj.data;
                document.getElementById('containerDiv').appendChild(div);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick='Count(this)'> Click to count </button>
        <div id='containerDiv'>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```